# Can we add variables and properties in interfaces in C#.NET?

Tags: c#

I want to know that how to add variables (i.e. with which access specifier) in interfaces and also can we write property in interfaces in C#.net?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should have been easy to find on the internet.

Interfaces are contracts to be fulfilled by implementing classes. Hence they can consist of *public* methods, properties and events (*indexers are permitted too*).

Variables in Interfaces - NO. Can you elaborate on why you need them? You can have variables in Base classes though.
Properties in Interfaces - Yes, since they are paired methods under the hood.
Members of an interface are implicitly public. You cannot specify access modifiers explicitly

```
public interface ISampleInterface
{
    // method declaration
    bool CheckSomething(object o);

    // event declaration
    event EventHandler ShapeChanged;

    // Property declaration:
    string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

See also

- [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)
- [Interface properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx(VS.80).aspx)
- [Interface events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: thnx! can u give me one example

Comment: I believe an interface can be declared with whatever scope you want, but all exposed functionality must be at that scope. I have never seen it or tried it as anything other than public.

Comment: No access modifiers, signatures only.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in interfaces, I don't think so but I'm not 100% certain?

And yes, you can have properties in interfaces. See the MSDN reference:
[Interface Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)